# Why fill, copy (dstList, srcList), shuffle, reverse, rotate Collections class methods take only List as argument?

Tags: java, list, collections

Is there any clear logic behind this: in Collections class the following methods take only List as argument

> fill, copy (dstList, srcList), shuffle, reverse, rotate

Those methods could take Queue, Deque just as well, for example.

Answer (score 4):

Well, this methods cannot take any `Collection`, since some `Collection`s don't have ordering (which means methods like `reverse` or `shuffle` would have no meaning) or don't allow duplicates (which means methods like `fill`  and `nCopies` would have no meaning).

While `Queue` and `Dequeue` have ordering and allow duplicates, the elements in these `Collection`s are supposed to be consumed in a specific order related to the order in which they were added (FIFO or LIFO), so perhaps methods like `shuffle` make less sense.

You could, however, use `LinkedList`s, which implement both `List` and `Deque` to call these methods on queues.